# Error: Buffer.write(string, encoding, offset[, length]) is no longer supported

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have started working on expressJs node Js but stuck at a point where the user inserts a data in the form and click on submit then get an error. I search so much about this error but not get a proper answer to resolve my issue. Please help me to out this problem.

500 Error: Buffer.write(string, encoding, offset[, length]) is no longer supported

```
at Buffer.write (buffer.js:763:11)
at MultipartParser.initWithBoundary (/media/iron/1d6c195f-2350-423c-a3f0-0500c92e580a/website/app/node_modules/connect/node_modules/formidable/lib/multipart_parser.js:61:17)
at IncomingForm._initMultipart (/media/iron/1d6c195f-2350-423c-a3f0-0500c92e580a/website/app/node_modules/connect/node_modules/formidable/lib/incoming_form.js:308:10)
at IncomingForm._parseContentType (/media/iron/1d6c195f-2350-423c-a3f0-0500c92e580a/website/app/node_modules/connect/node_modules/formidable/lib/incoming_form.js:250:12)
at IncomingForm.writeHeaders (/media/iron/1d6c195f-2350-423c-a3f0-0500c92e580a/website/app/node_modules/connect/node_modules/formidable/lib/incoming_form.js:129:8)
at IncomingForm.parse (/media/iron/1d6c195f-2350-423c-a3f0-0500c92e580a/website/app/node_modules/connect/node_modules/formidable/lib/incoming_form.js:97:8)
at /media/iron/1d6c195f-2350-423c-a3f0-0500c92e580a/website/app/node_modules/connect/lib/middleware/multipart.js:125:12
at noop (/media/iron/1d6c195f-2350-423c-a3f0-0500c92e580a/website/app/node_modules/connect/lib/middleware/multipart.js:22:3)
at multipart (/media/iron/1d6c195f-2350-423c-a3f0-0500c92e580a/website/app/node_modules/connect/lib/middleware/multipart.js:76:5)
at /media/iron/1d6c195f-2350-423c-a3f0-0500c92e580a/website/app/node_modules/connect/lib/middleware/bodyParser.js:57:9
```

Node Version: 6.2.2

Npm Version: 3.9.5

Thanks!!

Comment: Are you sure you're using `express` and not `connect`?

Comment: yes !! i m sure and im follow this article https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/build-a-complete-mvc-website-with-expressjs--net-34168

Comment: The first code example on that page is showing `var connect = require('connect')`, which suggests that it's using `connect`. It's a pretty old tutorial (2013), perhaps it's worthwhile to look for more recent tutorial as a lot has changed in 5 years.

Comment: Thanks!! @robertklep can you suggest me any recent tutorial??

Comment: Sorry, not really :( Perhaps this is a reasonable starting point: http://expressjs.com/en/resources/books-blogs.html

Answer (score 1):

I was able to resolve this by using npm update command on my express app.

Problem is with bodyParser module, this issue is fixed in latest versions of node.
npm update command helped to resolve this issue.

Here is the output after npm update and server restart.

> connect deprecated multipart: use parser (multiparty, busboy, formidable) npm module instead at node_modules\connect\lib\middleware\bodyParser.js:56:20
>
> connect deprecated limit: Restrict request size at location of read at node_modules\connect\lib\middleware\multipart.js:86:15
>
> connect deprecated methodOverride: use method-override npm module instead at app.js:24:17

Hope this helps to other users facing the same error.

Answer (score 1):

For me it was the issue coming due to the older version of Koa Better Body(koa-better-body) package. I upgraded it from 1.0.17 to 3.3.9 and then it was working fine.

Node Version : 10.19.0

NPM : 6.13.4

Framework : Koa 2